# Azure Powershell - Change Directory

Tags: powershell, azure

When I login to the new Azure Portal I see a drop-down at the top right that lets me select a "Directory" from a list of 2. When I login to azure using powershell cmdlet "Login-AzureRmAccount" I am connected to the wrong directory. How can I change to the other directory from within Powershell?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to specify the TenantID parameter when using Select-AzureRMSubscription:

```
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscripitionID <ID of sub> -TenantId <ID of Azure Tenant>
```

You can actually just specify the tennant to select the directory, without a subscription ID.

```
Select-AzureRmSubscription  -TenantId <ID of Azure Tenant>
```

Comment: Thanks Sam. For me, I found it worked only when I also provided subscription id. I was able to determine the azure AD tenant id by clicking the help icon in the top-right of the Azure portal, then clicking "Show Diagnostics". This displayed a Json file which included the Tenant Id.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the instructions explained [here](http://vcloud-lab.com/entries/microsoft-azure/how-to-switch-to-other-azure-ad-tenant-using-powershell-and-azure-cli).

Basically just type:

```
Get-AzTenant
```

You will see something like:

```
Id                                   Name           Category            Domains
--                                   ----           --------            -------
XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX MyDirectory      Home        {me.com, example1.com}
YYYYYYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYYYYYYY WorkDirectory    Home       {work.net, Adam.com,...}
```

Then, you choose the directory/tenant you want:

```
Set-AzContext -TenantId XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt125356.aspx 
In short, you can use the Select-AzureRmSubscription cmdlet to switch to the correct subscription.

Answer (score 1):

In azure portal, select **? Help + Support** select **Show diagnostics**. Here you find TenantID. Next step is to login.

```
$Credential = Get-Credential
Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $Credential -TenantId <ID of Azure Tenant>
```