# When does a tenant become a multi-tenant?

Tags: azure

I am having trouble understanding the [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-whatis#terminology) terminology on Multi Tenant.

> Multi-tenant: Azure tenants that access other services in a shared
>   environment, across multiple organizations, are considered
>   multi-tenant.

I understand the concept of a Mult-tenant SaaS database as explained [in the docs here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/saas-tenancy-app-design-patterns) which is similar to [Wikipedia's explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy)

But what is a multi-tenant tenant?

From the same terminology the definition of a tenant is

> Azure tenant: 
>   A dedicated and trusted instance of Azure AD that's automatically created when your organization signs up for a Microsoft cloud service subscription, such as Microsoft Azure, Microsoft Intune, or Office 365. An Azure tenant represents a single organization.

So presumably a multi tenant tenant represents multiple organisations.  I just don't see how.

It is a bit like calling a set a multi-set. A contradiction in terms.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/917070/azure-single-tenant-web-app-vs-multi-tenant

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/634134/creating-a-multi-tenant-ad-environment?rq=1

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-access-create-new-tenant

Comment: Check out Azure B2B and B2C: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/what-is-b2b, B2C: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview comparison of both: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/compare-with-b2c

Comment: Thanks @ElliotLabsLLC but these links dont seem to mention multi-tenant tenants.

Comment: They are multi tenants since they span multiple tenants, B2c is bridging your tenant with another partner's tenant (b2b means business to business). b2c is business to customer, it has the ability to federate with various oauth providers, hence spanning multiple tenants.

Comment: Isn't that like saying a set can become a multi-set? It's a contradiction in terms.

Comment: Imagine a service provider that has many customers (companies) they provide IT services for. Each and every customer has their own tenant, but they are hosted as a part of the service providers multi-tenant. None of the customers are able to look at each others tenants, but the service provider is able to change between the customers tenants seamlessly without having to login out/into the different tenants.

At least this is how it works with other products/services. However, I'm not sure what MS defines multi-tenant as, so this is just my two cents. :-)

Comment: @OnkelJ what application woud the service provider be using to look at those tenants?

Comment: Well, as I said, I don’t know the «MS way», but if I’d take a guess, they’d be changing through the web browser’s user icon, and in poweshell with a command and SSO takes care of the authentication, ref: https://serverfault.com/questions/778561/azure-powershell-change-directory

Answer (score 0):

I [cross posted here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fa4b50df-c786-48e5-967d-2671d233e13d/i-am-not-understanding-the-concept-of-multitenant-tenant-in-the-docs?forum=WindowsAzureAD) and it turns out that there is no such thing as a multi-tenant tenant.